# Why won't the current page on navigation menu stay changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a tumblr theme, and I asked a bit earlier without a code, so I put together this code if it will help you.

I have an if statement that if window.current.href == "the html of home" (which in this case I made the jsfiddle html underneath for testing purposes) and then .css to change the styling as I want it to be.
But it doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RichardWinter/c3vgy00n/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="headerMenu">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="http://whatchoodo.tumblr.com/">
                <span id="home">Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://whatchoodo.tumblr.com/Dirty">
                <span class="dirty">Dirty Jokes</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://whatchoodo.tumblr.com/Sport">
                <span id="sport">Sport</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://whatchoodo.tumblr.com/Memes">
                <span id="memes">Memes</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://whatchoodo.tumblr.com/Personal">
                <span id="personal">Personal Stuff</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    if (window.location.href == "http://jsfiddle.net/RichardWinter/c3vgy00n/2/") { 
        $("#home").css({
            border-bottom+color: #6DC176,
            border-bottom-style: 'solid', 
            border-bottom-width: 3px,
            color: #6DC176, 
            font-weight: 'bold',
        }); 
});
```

Comment: your code has syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of syntax errors. Especially, the object parameter that you are passing to jQuery `.css` is missing quotes on its properties and values. Also, you `if` is missing an end-brace.

This should go like this:

```
if (window.location.href == "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/") {
    $("#home").css({
        'border-bottom-color': '#6DC176',
            'border-bottom-style': 'solid',
            'border-bottom-width': '3px',
            'color': '#6DC176',
            'font-weight': 'bold',
    });
}
```

It is not working for you in Fiddle, also because fiddle uses a frame to show the results. You need to use the frame url to test.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/c3vgy00n/4/

Click "run" to see the CSS effect on "home".

.

Answer (score 0):

First, your JS has syntax errors, fixed like following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href == "http://jsfiddle.net/RichardWinter/c3vgy00n/2/") {
        $("#home").css({
            'border-bottom-color': '#6DC176',
            'border-bottom-style': 'solid', 
            'border-bottom-width': '3px',
            'color': '#6DC176', 
            'font-weight': 'bold'
        });
    } 
});
```

Second, the URL is not matching. The result part on jsfiddle is actually in an iframe (http://fiddle.jshell.net/RichardWinter/c3vgy00n/2/show/).

Third, I guess what you really want to modify is the anchor's (`<a>`) style, rather than its child `<span>` (this is my assumption, correct me if I was wrong).

Comment: I see! How can I check the result part on Tumblr as well? I fixed the syntax errors and added http://whatchoodo.tumblr.com/ instead of the jsfiddle link but it still wont work. That is the link to the homepage if you wanna see as well.
Oh, and I changed the id's from the spans to the links around them which, again, you were correct by saying they are the ones I want to style. Thanks, Richard.

Comment: @RichardLundWinther the URL is `"http://whatchoodo.tumblr.com/"`, not `"whatchoodo.tumblr.com/"`. Protocol (http/https) is part of the URL.

Comment: @RichardLundWinther you could run `alert(window.location.href)` to see the correct URL for every page.

Comment: @RichardLundWinther the code is running before you include jQuery, so `$` is not defined then. Place your code after you include jQuery.

Comment: That did it! I'm gonna watch out for that trap from now on... It seems like that was the reason some other less important scripts I added didn't work as well! 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RichardLundWinther One more thing to keep in mind: even if you have jQuery at that time, it won't work as well. Because it's still ahead of your HTML, so when it runs, `#home` is not parsed in DOM at all, the element is not existing yet.